# How to implement ModuleReader for JPMS?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

I try to understand how to implement custom ModuleFinder. For this I need to implement custom ModuleReference, and for ModuleReference I need to implement ModuleReader. This is my code:

```
ModuleReference ref = new ModuleReference(moduleDescriptor, Paths.get(path).toUri()) {

@Override
public ModuleReader open() throws IOException {
    ModuleReader moduleReader = new ModuleReader() {
        @Override
        public Optional<URI> find(String name) throws IOException {
            //LINE X
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public Stream<String> list() throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    };
    return moduleReader;
}
```

};

I can't understand what I should write at `LINE X`. As I understand this module is not loaded by JVM, so must I give a URI to resource inside jar that is on filesystem? Something like `/home/Sam/temp/foo-1.jar!META-INF/temp.txt` or what?

Comment: a little confused by the question, shouldn't the case be, you explicitly calling out the contracts since this is an overriden implementation?

Comment: @nullpointer Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: You could look the internal implementations of `ModuleReader` for inspiration; according to Intellij there are 9 such implementations (in Java 10). For instance, [`ModuleReferences$JarModuleReader`](https://github.com/dmlloyd/openjdk/blob/0301fc792ffd3c7b506ef78887af250e0e3ae09e/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/module/ModuleReferences.java#L224).

Comment: @Pavel_K I was asking, why are you creating a `ModuleReader` of your own and what is your intention of creating a ModuleFinder of your own? I was expecting that is something you know better(contracts) and hence can write your own overridden implementation of the abstract class in general.

Comment: @nullpointer I want to try to add a .war file to JPMS layer, but default ModuleFinder doesn't allow to do it. I opened an issue here https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8203330  and Alan Bateman suggested to create custom ModuleFinder.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you for the link, it can help a lot.

Comment: If you are developing a ModuleFinder to support modules in WAR files then it does mean developing a new ModuleReference to locate the module, and a ModuleReader to access the contents of the module. I think the question is asking about the `name` parameter. This is the name of the resource in the module. If the module contains a resource named "META-INF/temp.txt" then the reader's find method will locate it and return a URI to that resource.

Comment: This is a topic more suited for discussion on jigsaw-dev.

Comment: @AlanBateman I posted a suggestion to jigsaw-dev mailing list. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2018-September/013921.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of ModuleReader can be found in this mailing thread http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jigsaw-dev/2018-September/013924.html